# Which HTML/JS widget to display this balsamiq control?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, balsamiq

I did mockups in balsamiq & they have this nice widget, which

- Allowed to select a value, out of two values. Works really nicely on touchscreens
- Can be used to Display two values & highlighting the selected one

Example:
[image: Widget]

What the options to implement a widget similar to shown in picture via HTML/CSS & JS?

Comment: Quite a few, what have you tried? Have you found anything at all from a search?

Comment: I have looked at http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/radio.html It does want I want it do. Still, I opened the question to knows if that is a good choice or there are better options availabe.

hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I present below iterates through all `fieldset` elements, and if all the inputs therein are of `type="radio"`, hides them and appends `span` elements (of `class="buttonRadio"`) in their place, using the text from their relevant `label` elements. It also binds `click` events to the appended `span` elements, and triggers the `change` event on the original `input`s and also adds the 'checked' class-name to the clicked/touched element, while removing that class it from its siblings:

```
$('fieldset').each(
    function() {
        var legend = $(this).find('legend').text();
        if ($(this).find('input').length == $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').length) {
            var that = $(this),
                len = that.find('input[type="radio"]').length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $('<span />')
                    .text($('label')
                          .eq(i).text())
                    .addClass('buttonRadio')
                    .attr('data-fromID',that.find('input:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id'))
                    .appendTo(that);
            }
        }
    }).on('click','.buttonRadio',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-fromID');
        $(this).addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
        $('#' + id).click().trigger('change');
    }).find('label, input[type="radio"]').css('display','none');​
```

This uses the following CSS to style those elements:

```
.buttonRadio {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

.buttonRadio.checked {
    background-color: #ffa;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/C7Yfj/).

---

**Edited** to amend the jQuery a little:

1. cached the `$(this)` object a little earlier in this version,
2. remembered to use the `legend` variable that I assigned in the first incarnation but forgot to actually use...sigh.
3. also hid the actual `<legend></legend>` element:

   ```
   $('fieldset').each(
       function() {
           var that = $(this),
               legend = that.find('legend').text();
           $('<span />').text(legend).addClass('legend').appendTo(that);
           if (that.find('input').length == that.find('input[type="radio"]').length) {
               var len = that.find('input[type="radio"]').length;
               for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   $('<span />')
                       .text($('label')
                         .eq(i).text())
                       .addClass('buttonRadio')
                       .attr('data-fromID',that.find('input:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id'))
                       .appendTo(that);
               }
           }
       }).on('click','.buttonRadio',function(){
           var id = $(this).attr('data-fromID');
           $(this).addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
           $('#' + id).click().trigger('change');
       }).find('label, input[type="radio"], legend').css('display','none');​
   ```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/C7Yfj/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).